# using shell_exec to send email fail

Tags: php, linux, shell, email, permissions

I have been struggling with sending an email from my php project for days. I think I got something but it doesn't work.

here is what I did:
I first installed mailutils with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install mailutils
```

with it I can send Emails to myself (trough shell).
I used the following command to send myself an email, AND IT WORKS !!!!

```
mail -s subject mymail888@gmail.com <<< message
```

but in my php project this line does not work:

```
shell_exec("mail -s subject mymail888@gmail.com <<< message");
```

I think it has something to do with the permission of my project but I do not know how to change the permission of the `mail` command.

Comment: Did you try the PHP function `mail()`.. If not try looking at the manual for it

Comment: @PetrHejda , I have tried using it.. the problem is that it did not work.. I'm in a localhost and I heard that might be a problem ..

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a compelling reason not to, you should really use PHP's built-in `mail()` function. If you needed anything more than the basic feature's of `mail()` arguably and in the main, most CMS' and frameworks that have an email send feature, will simply be wrapping the `mail()` function.

Having said that, I don't know what your environment setup is like, so try using one of `system()`, `passthru()` or `exec()` instead, which accept varying number of additional error-code and output parameters that you can dump/echo to see what the *actual* error was when running your arbitrary command-line commands.

Comment: I have tried all of the following:
$s=passthru("mail -s subject mymail888@gmail.com <<< message");

$s=  shell_exec("mail -s subject mymail888@gmail.com <<< message");

$s=  exec("mail -s subject mymail888@gmail.com <<< message");


$s=  system("mail -s subject mymail888@gmail.com <<< message");


mail("mymail888@gmail.com", "did you get it?", "did you?" );

mail returned "true" but no mail was sent..

Comment: You're expecting each of those functions to do the same thing, but they don't. For a start they don't all return something so `$s` may not contain what you'd expect.

What do you get if you run this:

`$output = array();`
`$return = 0;`
`$command = "mail -s subject mymail888@gmail.com <<< message";
`exec ($command, $output, $return);`
`var_dump($output, $return);`

Comment: I get "array (size=0)
  empty
int 2"

Comment: `$output` being empty means the command didn't return anything. A value of "2" for `$return` is the exit code most commonly meaning "No such file or directory".

Try the following, each time dumping `$output` and `$return`:

* Passing a full-path to mail e.g. "/usr/bin/mail" (Or wherever mutt or whatever you're using is installed on your system)
* _Not_ using shell redirection (The "<<<" part) in your command, and instead using something like the following command:

`echo “My message” | mail -s “My subject” me@mymail.co"`

Comment: I must admit I did not understand what you meant by "Passing a full-path to mail e.g. "/usr/bin/mail" or why there is an 'echo' in the command you wrote..  What I did try is changing the command to:         $command= '“My message” | /usr/sbin/sendmail -s “My subject” mymail888@gmail.com' ;
(where /usr/sbin/sendmail is my sendmail_path and the output this time was : array (size=0)
  empty
int 1  .... (no email was sent..)